# Hide button when i submit using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use 4 buttons in my script when i click any one of the button other three buttons should be hidden. Can anyone suggest me to work out this in jquery or javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [jQuery Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery.hide()

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
    $('#button2').hide();
    $('#button3').hide();
    $('#button4').hide();
});
```

Comment: Or just `$("#button2, #button3, #button4").hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose it should be like

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('button').hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```